# Automatically compare two textboxes value, no button

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey guys im trying to compare two textboxes automatically when the user inputs data. The first textbox gets its value from 2 comboboxes where you select % and it calculates to this textbox. 
The other textbox is the same and this one can not be greater than the previous textbox.
This is what ive been working on but its only working if you enter the data with the keyboard, which i am not.

```
tbRegPersPlacÅrArb.KeyUp += textBox_Compare;
        Kvarattfördela.KeyUp += textBox_Compare;

  private void textBox_Compare(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Color cBackColor = Color.Red;
        if (tbRegPersPlacÅrArb.Text == Kvarattfördela.Text)
        {
            cBackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        tbRegPersPlacÅrArb.BackColor = cBackColor;
        Kvarattfördela.BackColor = cBackColor;
    }
```

Comment: `KeyUp` may not be the right event to handle, then.  maybe [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Can't you compare 2 values at where you calculate? After you set .Text property, set bcolor immediatley?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the compare function and call it on the "Text Changed" event handler of both the text boxes.
You can create the following Comapare function:

```
private void Compare()
{
    Color cBackColor = Color.Red;
    if (tbRegPersPlacÅrArb.Text == Kvarattfördela.Text)
    {
        cBackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    tbRegPersPlacÅrArb.BackColor = cBackColor;
    Kvarattfördela.BackColor = cBackColor; 
}
```

and call it in the TextChanged event handlers of both the text boxes.

```
private void tbRegPersPlacÅrArb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Compare();
    }
private void Kvarattfördela_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Compare();
    }
```

This should help.